# Elastic Search Kibana TimeStamp key missing

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a dataset with timestamp info in it. I used Python/PYES package to insert the data into elastic search following the [tutorial](http://pyes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/usage.html) here.

Then, I installed Kibana in the same machine and modified the js. I have no problem opening the Kibana web page and see my data there.

However, when I tried to create a histogram graph. It popped up the error below:

```
× Oops! FacetPhaseExecutionException[Facet [0]: (key) field [@timestamp] not found]
```

just for your information, my mapping looks like this:

```
mapping = {
 'timestamp': {
     'type': 'date'
  },
 'productNumber': {
     'type': 'string'
  },
 'manufacturer': {
     'type': 'string'
 },
 'stock': {
     'type': 'integer'
 },
 'unitPrice': {
     'type': 'float'
 }
}
```

Also, if you go to the [demo page](http://demo.kibana.org/#/dashboard) of Kibana, you can see there are @ sign in front of the timestamp column and I don't know if that is the problem.

[image]

Anyone has an idea what I did wrong, I want to display my data using histogram :(

Comment: I have exact same issue, did u figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

On my end, I imported data from a MySQL timestamp field and had to remove the "@" for Kibana to use it. Also, in my mapping, I see :

```
"lastSession": {
    "type": "date",
        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
     },
```

Perhaps the format helps.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't know if this question is still open, but anyway:*

The error states that it can't find `@timestamp`. You showed your mapping starting with `timestamp`. I think what you're missing is that `@timestamp` and `timestamp` are two completely different fields!

To fix this either change the documents and introduce `@timestamp` and set that to the values of `timestamp` or go to the configuration of the histogram and put `timestamp` into the field "Time Field" in the "Time Options".